# Unable to resolve "Unable to find draggable element with id: " issue when trying to use react-beautiful dnd

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I've tried ways including change react and react-dom versions to v17.0.0, and removing strict mode but I'm still facing this issue and can't seem to make it work. Help would be appreciated.

List.js

```
const List = ({ id, title, tasks, notes, setNotes }) => {
<Droppable droppableId={id.toString()}>
    {(provided) => (
      <div
        className="cards"
        {...provided.droppableProps}
        ref={provided.innerRef}
      >
        {tasks.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <Card
              key={item.id}
              id={item.id}
              index={index}
              message={item.message}
            />
          );
        })}
        {provided.placeholder}
      </div>
    )}
  </Droppable>
}
```

Card.js

```
 const Card = ({ id, index, message }) => {
   return (
<Draggable draggableId={id.toString()} index={index}>
  {(provided) => (
    <div
      className="card-wrapper"
      {...provided.droppableProps}
      {...provided.dragHandleProps}
      ref={provided.innerRef}
    >
      <div className="card-message">{message}</div>
    </div>
  )}
</Draggable>
 );
 };
```

So basically, I have a list that has a series of card containing todos inside it. Above is the code which has been causing trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, silly mistake I was declaring droppableProps inside the draggable container instead of draggableProps.